# WCF: using memorystream to transfer bitmaps in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, jpeg, memorystream

I am using WCF for communication between client and server program on the same machine. Earlier I used Bitmaps to transfer video frames to the client. It was successful with WCF, but I only have 6 megabytes / sec LAN. Transferring 1.2Mb every second would block the LAN. I decided to JPEG encode the captured Bitmaps from the camera. It is possible to save a JPEG on the disk from a bitmap, or to a Memorystream. I created a

```
[MessageContract]
public class RemoteResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.MemoryStream jpegImage;
}
```

I return this back from the (I)LiveImageService.
As I get it out in the client:    RemoteResponse ret = client.GetLiveImage();

```
MemoryStream returnedImage = returnedResponse.jpegImage;
returnedImage.Position = 0L;
returnedImage.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
args.image = returnedImage;
```

I do this in the event handler:

```
args.image.Position = 0L;
args.image.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
//bitmap = new Bitmap(args.image);
bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(args.image);
```

It gives me a "parameter is not valid" exception.
I have read that this is a buggy solution of Microsoft. Actually the
retreived stream is believed to be 21 bytes long because there is a trailing
zero \0 at the end of the leading "System.Drawing.Bitmap"\0. That is why the
processing of the image is stopped.

I have read a solution that avoids this:

```
byte[] arr = PdfReader.FlateDecode(PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)obj), true);

System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);

System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new  System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);

Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, bmd.Scan0, arr.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); // here it is the trick
arr = ms.GetBuffer(); // now I replace my incorrect image format bytes for the correct ones
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
image.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

How does the last arr = ... have any effect? It is not used anymore later?
So I don't understand.

update:

On a Microsoft website: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f9e39595-04ca-42ae-a353-eb1a08602631/resolved-creating-image-file-parameter-is-not-valid?forum=netfxbcl

I rewrote the example so:

```
public static Bitmap DecodeJPEGFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream stream, int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
{
    string content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    byte[] arr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
    //byte[] arr = PdfReader.FlateDecode(PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)obj), true);

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new
    System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);

    Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, bmd.Scan0, arr.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // here it is the trick
        arr = ms.GetBuffer(); // now I replace my incorrect image format bytes for the correct ones
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        Bitmap ret = new Bitmap(image);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I can see the image in the Picturebox, but it has only 2 lines, flickering.
If I obscure the camera I see that it darkens. So the data comes through now. But I cannot reconstruct my JPEG live data.

I was able to decode the JPEG data, only with saving it to disk.
So I've got the image without error. I tried to save the image only
temporarily and delete after.

```
public static Bitmap DecodeJPEGFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream stream, int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat)
{
    try
    {
        if(File.Exists("c:\\imagecache.jpg") == true)
                File.Delete("c:\\imagecache.jpg");

        //using (FileStream file = new FileStream("c:\\imagecache.jpg", FileMode.CreateNew, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using (FileStream file = File.Open("c:\\imagecache.jpg", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(file);
            //JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(file, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            file.Close();
            file.Dispose();
        }

        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];

        Bitmap jpeg;
        {
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo("c:\\imagecache.jpg");

                if (info.Length == 0)
                {
                    File.Delete("c:\\imagecache.jpg");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            System.GC.Collect();
            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();


            jpeg = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("c:\\imagecache.jpg");  //the process cannot access the file...
        }

        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        if (File.Exists("c:\\imagecache.jpg") == true)
                File.Delete("c:\\imagecache.jpg");

        return jpeg;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

I get the exception:   The process cannot access the file "imagecache.jpg",
because it is being used by another process. Exception comes at the FromFile.

```
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Bitmap retImage = (Bitmap)jpeg.Clone();
jpeg.Dispose();

if (File.Exists("c:\\imagecache.jpg") == true)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo("c:\\imagecache.jpg");
    fi.Delete();
}

    return retImage;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
finally
{
    stream.Dispose();
}
```

It is fixed so. Image.FromFile: the File remains locked until the Image is disposed.

So I cloned my Image and disposed the old one.
Before I've seen my Image, now nothing is visible.

Comment: Where did you find this solution? It may be helpful to read it in context.

Comment: I rewrote the example so:

Comment: Why are you mangling your byte stream through a UTF8 encoding and back? That's supposed to be image data. Also, when you do bmp.Save(), don't use jpeg format there; it'll degrade the image quality for no reason.

Comment: Image quality has to be degraded.  Can anyone help me to better understand this code?

Comment: I call this function from an EventHandler. Is this a problem? I guess, that it is often called up, so it's threads are running parallel. ???

Comment: I was able to fix the crash:  The file remains locked until the Image is disposed. So I removed the last delete, and kept the first.